# html text output compression from rails (or apache/passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compression, apache2, rack, http-compression

i have a quite strange request: i want to "compress" all the output from a rails app; with this i do not mean gzip or any similar compression, i mean to reformat the whole output (preferably with apache/passenger but can also be a rack middleware or rails plugin)

anyone knows if something like this exists? any apache module out there? 
if not, what would be a good way to implement something like this?

just to be more clear what i want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    info!
    <!-- my comment -->
    </body>
</html>
```

should become

```
<html><head><title>page title</title></head><body>info!<!-- my comment --></body></html>
```

ideally, also comments and other shenanigans are removed, so ideally it would look like this

```
<html><head><title>page title</title></head><body>info!</body></html>
```

again, just to avoid having mod_deflate or gzip discussions again: i know that such things as gzip compressors exists. i am specifically searching for a way to text-filter with apache or rails (rack).

thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Are you using template caching at all?

Comment: I've been thinking about this myself - removing all white space between tags and perhaps replacing the white space in the body with &nbsp;

Comment: i think you need to write your own middleware to strip out the contents with gem 'nokogiri' and send the response back.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be feasible, but how about a deployment task that "cleans" all your templates?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. unfortunately, this is not what i am searching for. i would prefer to keep my code readable, but the output compressed. but thanks for the pointer.